# Wrap text around a picture except for the first line

Tags: positioning, line-breaking, wrapfigure

As the following minimal sample shows, a text wrapping around a picture starts wrapping with the first line. Including the `wrapfigure` in the text leads to strange paragraph breaks.

```
%----
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%----

    \begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{l}{0pt}
    \vspace{-30pt}
    \includegraphics{test}
\end{wrapfigure}    

\textbf{Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consetetur-sadipscing-elitr (1)}. Now starts text \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions how to avoid the first line form wrapping around a picture like in the following scheme?

[image]

### Edit:

I have found a way to solve the problem for a minimal example using `picinpar` and a `window` environment.

`\begin{window}[<number of lines>, <align>, \includegraphics[]{<file>}, {<caption-text>}]`

```
%---
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
%---

\begin{document}

\begin{window}[1, l, \includegraphics[]{test}, {}]
\textbf{Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consetetur-sadipscing-elitr (1)}. 
Now starts text \lipsum[1]
\end{window}


\end{document}
```

But still I want to use `schemeref` to add numbering within a picture and therefore I need a `figure` environment and no such solution with `window`.

Any ideas regarding that?

Comment: adding the `wrapfigure` environment between the heading line and the text doesn't work for you? (I'd recommend you used a paragraph break between them  too)

Comment: actually no, i tried to do it that way, but especially with long "heading lines" it's not working. inline `\textbf{(\textit{R})-2-methoxy-2-oxo-1-phenylethyl 3,6-dimethoxy-2-(2-methoxynaphthalen-1-yl)-benzoate (15)}. Now starts text \begin{wrapfigure}[]{l}{0pt}
    \vspace{-30pt}
    \includegraphics{test}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]` <br/> Question is here, where to include the wrapfigure and i can't see a good way to do it like that, you agree?

Comment: The first line starts to the right of the figure for me, without any changes to your MWE. So perhaps you have some older libraries.  Is that what you want, or do you want the output as produced by @Stefan's answer?

Comment: @PeterGrill. The MWE's first line starts right of the picture indeed and i am looking for a solution to have a left-aligned headline. Stefans Answer works pretty good, and it looks exactly how it should. Except the schemeref-functionality, i still need that.

Comment: Can you incorporate `schemeref` into your MWE to show the problem?

Comment: @PeterGrill. Therefore a specific image-file is needed which has a temporary-number, which is then substituted by \schemeref[TMP]{label}. After a second compilation run, all tmp-numbers are then chronologically filled with the right number. So, i think it is pretty hard to have a minimal working example here...

Comment: ... or is there a way to introduce a specific image file into a minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of a hack as a solution would be to push down the image a little and use a negative indentation for the first line like below.
I put the code into the macro `\parwithleftwrapfig` because it's important to correctly end paragraphs before and after the figure and reset the original indentation...

Note that you have to explicitly specify the width of the wrapfigure for this macro to work...

EDIT: I inserted an optional parameter to show that you can still use arbitrary code.

EDIT2: Adapted solution to access internal `wrapfig`-var to allow for automatic width adjustment. Note that internal vars of packages may change on updates without notice.

```
%----
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%----

\makeatletter
\newlength{\oldparindent}
\newcommand{\parwithleftwrapfig}[4][]
{ %
    \par %
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{#2} %
        \vspace*{\baselineskip} %
        \includegraphics{#3} %
        #1 %
    \end{wrapfigure}    %
    \setlength{\oldparindent}{\parindent} %
% %  To allow automatic width adjustment we access internal spacing var of package wrapfig:
    \addtolength{\parindent}{-\wd\WF@box} %
% %  instead of using the provided width:
%    \addtolength{\parindent}{-#2} %
    \addtolength{\parindent}{-\columnsep} %
    #4 \par %
    \setlength{\parindent}{\oldparindent} %
    \par %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textbf{First paragraph}. \lipsum[1]
%
\parwithleftwrapfig[{\caption{This is a figure.}\label{fig:afigure}}]{0\textwidth}{test}
    {\textbf{Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consetetur-sadipscing-elitr (1)}. Now starts text with references to figure \ref{fig:afigure}. \lipsum[1]}

\textbf{Another paragraph}. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice. it works fine for the minimal example.

Comment: It gets problematic, when used in a real life example for my thesis. Because there, I am using  schemeref for adding numbers within pictures/let latex do it and therefore i need the figure-environment to be still able to have the \schemeref functionality. I don't know if such options are still possible in your hack solution.

Comment: hm, and it's a pitty that the automatic specification of size doesn't work for this solution.

Comment: Hey @JMR, in my example I wrapped the code into a macro because this is easier to use and makes sure that the reset of parindent is not forgotten. You can still put anything you want into the `wrapfigure` environment, either with additional parameters or by manually inserting the macro code. To show what I mean I added a new optional parameter to the example.

Comment: As to the auto-width problem: There certainly is a possibility to modify the macro to adjust dynamically to the width, but that's a different question because one would need access to the generated boxes. Maybe start a new question if nobody find's it here.

Comment: With the update on your solution i was able to finde a way to incorporate /schemeref into the work-around. So, i guess. that's it. It is a solution. I would not say it's a straight-forward, simple and beatiful solution, but it works! Thanks a lot for your patience and effort.

Comment: I provided an update using wrapfig's internal box for adjustment. See my edited code. Note 2 things: 1. Don't forget the `\makeat...` commands if you copy the code. 2. Spacing is different if you use auto width (a line above the pic is omitted), so you might have to adapt spacing.