# Placing a figure that occupies 2 columns

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column, ieeetran

Thanks for reading my thread. I have a two-columned IEEE format journal latex, and I want to insert a wide figure. Here is my code

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
  \centering   
  \begin{overpic}{profiles.eps}
     \put(40,35){\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{pline.png}}  
  \end{overpic}
\caption{MyCaption}
\label{fig_index}
\end{figure*}
```

The simplied version is not working either:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
  \centering   
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{profiles.eps}
\caption{MyCaption}
\label{fig_index}
\end{figure*}
```

Here is the packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\textsc{e}}
```

The problem I have is the figure does grow to two-column wide, but it moves all the way down to the end of the document. I tried removing the overlayed image, but it does not work at all. Anyone have any idea how I can make it work? This my first latex work, so I appreciate if you can paste some code I can read. Thanks!

Comment: It could be that the actual image is too wide or tall for the page and gets shifted towards the end. Do you receive any kind of warning about this in your `.log`? How about removing all the text in your article and using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) to generate dummy text and give us some reproducible code?

Comment: You can try the window environnement: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47853/wrap-text-around-a-picture-except-for-the-first-line it's a quite similar question but not exactly the same ;)

Comment: @Werner I even shrink the image down to 10%, pretty small, but still the image stays at the bottom of the article.

Comment: you have loaded multicol,are you using `multicols` or the standard 2-column setting? the behaviour of * floats is rather different in the two implementations,  Also * floats do not support `h` and you have omitted `p` which makes it likely the float goes to the end. It _always_ helps if you post a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using a template from IEEE. I don't think it uses multicol initially. The template is two-columned which I don't know why. I added multicol because I saw someone online using this code to make the image span two columns. I apologize that I did not paste enough code. My script is so long and I even have no idea what I should post can help people here. I post all that I think is relevant. If you want more, please let me know clearly what you would like.

Comment: Have you tried `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{profiles.eps}` instead of `\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{profiles.eps}`? By the way, in two-column documents double-wide floats can only be placed at the top of a page (Well, on a floats-only page it'll be centered vertically on the page...), so it's counterproductive to provide a location specifier such as `[ht!]`. I'd omit the location specifier.

Comment: OK. I put the same code somewhere else in the text, and the image shows up on the top of the page on the same page as the figure code is inserted. I have no idea how this thing is working. But I guess one of the comments makes sense, which is by Werner. However I not sure why even when the image is down sized to 10%, it still at the bottom of the article. Thank you all of you.

Comment: Did you remove the `[ht!]` location specifiers? Incidentally, how *tall* is your image? If it's taller than `0.5\textheight`, the parameter `\dblfloatpagefraction` (default value: 0.5) may be causing the placement of the float to be delayed until the very end of the document. One way to tell if that parameter is to blame is to recompile the document with `\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{0.8}` and again `\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{0.2}` in the preamble.

Comment: To figure out which code you need to post, keep taking stuff out and compiling your document. When it stops demonstrating the problem, put the last thing you removed back in (and, if appropriate, try removing something different). The code is needed if your document is otherwise problem-free. The code is not needed if deleting it produces a document which still has the problem.

Comment: To give an answer here we'll need a proper MWE including some place holder showing the size of the image. The discussion above shows that there are various variables to the problem to consider and we don't know what you are really doing.